# Where to Initialize lateinit ? Giving error "kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property db has not been initialized"

Tags: android, kotlin

MainActivity.kt

```
 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  lateinit var db:Database
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
       db=Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext,Database::class.java,"Users").build() //Error is shown here
    }

}
```

AddUserFragment.kt

```
class AddUserFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_user, container, false)

    view.btn_add.setOnClickListener {
        val id=et_Uid.text.toString()
        val name=et_Name.text.toString()
        val email=et_Email.text.toString()

        val users=Users(id,name,email)

        val mainActivity=MainActivity()
        mainActivity.db.myDao().addUser(users) //Error is shown here
        Toast.makeText(activity,"Added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    return  view
}}
```

Where to initialize db so not to get kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property db has not been initialized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating fresh instance of MainActivity which is not required!

Every Fragment has the `activity` instance which they associated with

Just cast that `activity` as `MainActivity`

```
(activity!! as MainActivity).db.myDao().addUser(users)
```

Comment: Thank you it worked.. Can you explain why that error occured in my code.

Comment: @PawanAcharya You tried to instantiate an Activity (where you typed `mainActivity=MainActivity()`). You should never instantiate an Activity. That is handled by the OS. A Fragment is attached to an Activity when it is created, and you can obtain that reference via `fragment.activity`.